# jets3t and Downloading Files from AmazonS3 with Different Name

Tags: amazon-s3, jets3t

We're using Amazon S3 for file storage and recently found out that we need to keep some sort of directory structure. Since S3 doesn't allow that, we know we can name the files according to their structure for storage. For example...

```
abc/123/draft.doc
```

What I want to know is if I want to provide a public link to this particular file is there anyway that the file can simply be draft.doc instead of abc/123/draft.doc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid.  After some more investigation I realized that by creating a GET url to the resource, I get exactly what I need.